# How to determine regulator's components values?

Tags: voltage-regulator, potentiometer

[image: regulator circuit]

The final goal is to have an output (u0) of 22 V. The only information given is the uBE value of 0.7 V and the maximum load current of 1 A.

I'm having a hard time determining basically every value involved in this circuit. It would be nice if someone could at least tell me where to start analyzing or something like that, since I can't find a circuit that looks like this anywhere.

Comment: Is this homework? You know the most important things already. Write them into the picture and see which voltages or currents you end up with. Then if there are unknowns left, you can choose them quite freely.

Comment: Here is a starting hint; at 1A, Q2 (current limiting transistor) needs to turn on, so there will be a voltage drop across Rcc from which you can calculate Rcc.The input voltage must be greater than Vout + V(Rcc) + VCE(sat) + Vbe for Q1. There are a *lot* of specific solutions; choose a zener diode (5V might make the calculations simple).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will get you started with a *procedure* but you will need to choose appropriate parts and do the calculations.

1. **Choose a Zener**

Perhaps we might like to use one of [these](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/BZX84_SER.pdf) parts. Applying my engineers eye, I would personally choose the 6.2V part (but that is simply because of the specifications - anything below your target output voltage would do).

The current through \$R_{REF}\$ must be sufficient to keep the zener in proper regulation + the current through P1. That current (for the zener) is specified in the datasheet.

2. **Choose P1**;

A 10k trimpot would work nicely here (but as we are looking at an ideal amplifier it could easily be much larger).

As the datasheet linked shows the current for which Vz is specified, and the current through P1 will simply be Vz / P1, you can now calculate the maximum value of \$R_{REF}\$ if we know the minimum input voltage.

3 **Find the minimum input voltage**

The minimum input voltage will be \$V_{out} + V_{BE[Q1]} + v_{RCC} + V_{CE(sat)} Q1\$. I would assume \$V_{CE(sat)}\$ to be 0.2V and V(RCC) will be a Vbe bias at current limit, so you can now find the minimum input voltage.

For the output voltage set, assuming that the value at the non-inverting input of the [error amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_amplifier_(electronics)) is Vz when at the maximum output voltage, then you need to choose them such that the voltage across R4 is equal to Vz.

So from the voltage divider equation, \$ Vz = \frac {{V_o} \cdot {R4}} {R4 + R5}\$; note that the *ratio* of R4 and R5 is what is important.

From that, you *should* now be able to solve and keep in mind that there are multiple solutions given what you have shown us.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which opamp you specify, you may need substantial headroom above the 22 volts Vout.

And the Power Supply Rejection Ratio of the opamp becomes the PSRR of the regulator.

Picking a Vzener in the 5 volt to 6 volt range will give you near ZERO temperature coefficient, for free.